# Show method for DialogFragment not working in Android Version 2.3

Tags: datepicker, show, timepicker, dialogfragment

I am using DatePicker and Time Picker in my Application but I am getting an error while using it.

See the Code Below :

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
{
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) 
    {
        tv_date_value.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
}
```

This is the Package I have imported after googling :

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

The Problem occurs when I try to create an object of the DialogFragment and use the show() Method, it says:

The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Here is the Code for that:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(myActivity.getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

I am getting Error on `show()` method.

I am using this Date and Time Picker in a Class and not an Activity, So I am giving a reference of that Main Activity Class named : "myActivity".

Can anybody Please help me here???

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 0):

try using getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getFragmentManager();
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(fragmentManager,"datepicker");
```